# ConfigurationException: Unable to find custom indexer class 'StorageAttachedIndex'

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am having this error while trying to create a new custom index.
Is because of my cassandra setup? What can be done to solve this issue?

```
cqlsh:dblpa2> create CUSTOM INDEX ON publication(entries(authors)) USING 'StorageAttachedIndex';
ConfigurationException: Unable to find custom indexer class 'StorageAttachedIndex'
```

`cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0.6 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5`

I am using `Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it's not yet implemented in the open source Cassandra (you can track progress in [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16052), and read more in [specification](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CASSANDRA/CEP-7%3A+Storage+Attached+Index)).

As of right now it's [available](https://docs.datastax.com/en/storage-attached-index/6.8/sai/saiAbout.html) only in DataStax Enterprise and [DataStax Astra](https://astra.datastax.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Storage-attached indexes (SAI) is a feature in [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) and [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) but it's not available in open-source Apache Cassandra yet. This is the reason you are getting the `ConfigurationException` -- Cassandra 4.0 does not know anything about SAI.

DataStax donated the feature to the Apache Cassandra project in 2020 (see Cassandra enhancement proposal [CEP-7](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/7DZ4CQ)) which will be implemented in [CASSANDRA-16052](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16052).